# Any way to default RDP Smart Sizing to 'On'?

Tags: remote-desktop, default-settings

The exposition of the **Smart Sizing** option in the most recent versions of Windows RDP connections is fantastic.

I routinely am throwing my RDP windows on to secondary monitors though, and almost always turning on Smart Sizing via the context menu.

Is there any way to make it so Smart Sizing is **On** by default for all RDP connections?